# Fourier coefficients of a function and its derivative

Tags: complex-analysis, fourier-analysis, lebesgue-integral, fourier-series

Let's say we have a piecewise $C^1$, $2\pi$ periodic, piecewise Lipschitz continuous function $f$, that is, we can find $0=t_0<...<t_l=2\pi$ such that $f|(t_{j-1},t_{j})$ is Lipschitz continuous and $C^1$ for all $j=1,...,l$ and let $g = f'$ on $(t_0,t_1)\cup...\cup(t_{l-1},t_l)$. We denote $c_k, \gamma_k$ as the Fourier coefficients for $f$ and $g$ respectively. (then we know that the Fourier series for $f$ and $g$ converges to the function $f$ and $g$ respectively, Fourier's convergence theorem)

Now we can show using partial integration (by splitting up the intervals) that $c_k = -\frac{i}{k} \gamma_k$.

For a concrete example lets consider a function $f$ that takes on the value $1$ on $(0,\pi)$ and $-1$ on $(\pi,2\pi)$, additionally $f(0)=f(\pi)=0$

We can then take $g$ as the contant zero function, but then we have $\gamma_k = 0$ for all $k$, whereas we know that $c_k$ is not just all zeroes.

What's wrong here?

Here's my attempt to proof that $c_k = -\frac{i}{k} \gamma_k$:

$c_k = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{0}^{2\pi} e^{-ikx}f(x) \,dx = \frac{1}{2\pi}\sum_{j=1}^{l} \int_{t_{j-1}}^{t_j} (cos(kx)-isin(kx))f(x) \,dx = \frac{1}{2\pi}\sum_{j=1}^{l}[\frac{1}{k}sin(kx)f(x)\Big|_{t_{j-1}}^{t_j} - \int_{t_{j-1}}^{t_j} \frac{1}{k}sin(kx)g(x) \,dx] + \frac{i}{2\pi}\sum_{j=1}^{l}[\frac{1}{k}cos(kx)f(x)\Big|_{t_{j-1}}^{t_j} - \int_{t_{j-1}}^{t_j} \frac{1}{k}cos(kx)g(x) \,dx] = \frac{1}{2\pi k}[sin(k2\pi)f(2\pi)-sin(0)f(0)] - \frac{1}{2\pi k} \int_{0}^{2\pi} sin(kx)g(x) \,dx + \frac{i}{2\pi k} * 0 -\frac{i}{2\pi k} \int_{0}^{2\pi} cos(kx)g(x) \,dx = -\frac{i}{k}\gamma_k$

Comment: The function $f$  in your example is not continuous, so it cannot satisfy the Lipschitz condition.

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc sorry I wasn't clear enough, $f$ should be piecewise Lipschitz continuous

Comment: the result $c_k = \frac{i}{k} \gamma_k$ is simply not true unless $f$ is absolutely continuous (so in particular continuous); now if $f$ is bounded variation, one can write $df$ as a sum of an absolutely continuous measure and a singular one and the result sort of holds with care - in this case $df$ has jumps so some Dirac singular measures are around giving eventually non zero $\gamma_k$ so the $c_k$, while indeed the absolutely continuous part is zero

Comment: @Conrad But why? We can simply divide up the intervals so $f$ is absolutely continuous there and do partial integration. It follows that $c_k = -\frac{i}{k}\gamma_k$, what do we need $f$ to be absolutely continuous for?

Comment: why don't you try it for your example and see where it fails for your function $f$ above - when you divide intervals, you do not generally have periodicity of $\sin nx, \cos nx$ at the new ends so the evaluation terms in partial integration do not generally cancel even if $f$ periodic on the split interval; for example on $[0, \pi]$ the integral of $1 \times \sin x$ is not zero and if you use integration by parts to differentiate $1$ and get the zero integral, you notice that the evaluation terms at $0, \pi$ are $1, -1$ respectively so difference doesn't cancel

Comment: @Conrad I've tried it out, sorry. Yes we don't have the periodicity but then by the telescoping property all cancels out and we're left with $\frac{1}{2\pi k}[sin(k2\pi)f(2\pi)-sin(0)f(0)]$ which equals to zero due to periodicity of $f$. I'll try to type the whole proof out in the post, but it might take a while since I'm not really good with Latex yet

Comment: @Conrad I've added the "proof" to the post, I hope you can help me spot where the error is, thanks a lot

Comment: I've noticed the error, it was a stupid mistake. Thank you guys.

Comment: just in case - the error is that the sums $\sum_{j=1}^{l}[\frac{1}{k}sin(kx)f(x)\Big|_{t_{j-1}}^{t_j} $ do not telescope since $f$ jumps at the $t_j$ so the values at same $t_j$ are different in the two sums in which those appear and same with the cosine sums

Comment: @Conrad Yes, that's why we need $f$ to be continuous, thanks :)